# D3js map marker collision detection

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Is there an example floating around of collision detection that avoids collision by manipulating radius rather than x,y coordinates? I'm aware of the examples Mike Bostock and others have put together, but I'm not using a force graph and my points are geographic and can't have their coordinates manipulated.

My best-guess implementation would be to begin with circles of radius 0, iterate over them and increase their individual radii as long as they don't collide with another circle. I think this would make a fantastic visualization, but I'm not sure how to efficiently determine whether one circle collides with another.

---

JSBin of my map with inline D3js (JavaScript tab is simply holding a 600kb GeoJSON dataset): http://jsbin.com/tapuhefamu/1/edit?html,output

Notice how the markers overlap when zoomed, it doesn't seem like a big deal in the fiddle (just zoom in further, right?) but the map I'm working with has ~2,000 pins clustered in only a few counties which need to display an informative DIV when clicked. Some pins are almost completely obscured and aren't able to be interacted with because of the overlap.

Comment: If you can provide a sample fiddle, I'd give it a try.

Comment: Like a [circle packing](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063530)?

Comment: Does Mike's Visualising Algorithms (http://bost.ocks.org/mike/algorithms/) page have anything that can help you?  Not exactly what you're looking for, but shouldn't be too difficult to adapt.

Comment: @Ben Thanks, but nothing quite. I have a map projection with certain geolocations pinned as svg circles. When visualizing the map, many of the circles overlap and it looks like a mess.

I need to find a way to load them with a radius of 0 and apply some delta to each radius. When two circumference parameters collide then their radius will stop increasing, but other free nodes will continue to increase and so on iteratively.

I've solved the problem, I just have to find a way to detect the collision. Think this is kind of a "SOF isn't going to do your job for you" question.

Comment: Maybe post an example of what you've currently got so at least others have something to work with when suggesting a solution.  Whilst what you're proposing sounds OK, something concrete would make things easier to understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have coded up something for you.  Detecting the collision is pretty easy, basically calculate the distance between the two center points, and if the distance is less than the two radii added together, then they must have collided.

I had some issues with jsbin, so I've turned it into a gist, which you can view at http://bl.ocks.org/benlyall/6a81499abf7a0e2ad304

The interesting bits are:

1. Add a `radiusStep` parameter - use this to balance the trade off between the number of iterations, and the amount of potential overlap between nodes.

   ```
   radiusStep = 0.01,
   ```
2. Remove the radius scaling from the zoom handler:

   ```
   zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom",function() {
           g.attr("transform","translate("+ d3.event.translate.join(",")+")scale("+d3.event.scale+")");
           //g.selectAll("circle")
           //.attr("r", nodeRadius / d3.event.scale);
           g.selectAll("path")
               .style('stroke-width', countyBorderWidth / d3.event.scale )
               .attr("d", path.projection(projection));
   }),
   ```
3. Create a new structure to keep track of whether a node has collided with another, the radius and also the x and y position (pre calculated with your projection)

   ```
   nodes = nodeGeoData.map(function(n) {
       var pos = projection(n);
       return {
           collided: false,
           x: pos[0],
           y: pos[1],
           r: 0
       };
   });
   ```
4. Two new functions to work with detecting the collision and expanding the radius until the collision is detected.

   ```
   function tick() {
       nodes.forEach(collided);

       nodes.forEach(function(n) {
           if (!n.collided) {
               n.r += radiusStep;
               if (n.r > nodeRadius) {
                   n.r = nodeRadius;
                   n.collided = true;
               }
           }
       });
   }
   ```

   This `tick` function first calls collide on each node to determine if it has collided with any other.  It then increases the radius by `radiusStep` of any node that has not collided.  If the radius becomes larger than the `nodeRadius` parameter, then it sets the radius to that value and marks it as collided to stop it being increased.

   ```
   function collided(node, i) {
       if (node.collided) return;

       nodes.forEach(function(n, j) {
           if (n !== node) {
               var dx = node.x - n.x, dy = node.y - n.y,
                   l = Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);

               if (l < node.r + n.r) {
                   node.collided = true;
                   n.collided = true;
               }
           }
       });
   }
   ```

   The collided function checks each node to see if has collided with any other (except itself, for obvious reasons).  If it detects a collision then both nodes in the comparison are marked as collided.  To detect the actual collision the differences in the x and y position are calculated and then using Pythagoras the distance between them is calculated.  If that distance is less than the radii of the two nodes added together, then a collision occurs.
5. The `drawMap` function is updated to calculate the radii before drawing the nodes.

   ```
   while (nodes.filter(function(n) { return n.collided; }).length < nodes.length) {
       tick();
   }
   ```

   This will basically just call the `tick` function until all nodes are marked as collided.
6. The `drawNodes` function is updated to use the new `nodes` data structure:

   ```
   function drawNodes(nodes) {
       g.selectAll('circle').data(nodes).enter().append("circle")
           .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
           .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; })
           .attr("r", function(d, i) { return d.r; })
           .attr("class", "map-marker");
   }
   ```

   The changes here just reference the `x`, `y` and `r` attributes of each node object created earlier.

Though this works, and seems to be pretty effective, it is naive and will quickly get bogged down, since the combination of the `tick` and `collided` functions is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: do you know any good example of how do I prevent the circle from colliding with each other by, detecting the collision and move it next to each other, almost similar like quadtree but my problem is I'm using the coordinate for marker on the Google Maps canvas. Thank you

Comment: it's like the circle packing but I don't know how to implement it using coordinate on the Google Maps